# Inclusion of prior knowledge about forecast to a (Bayesian) time series model

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, forecasting, bsts

I am trying to construct an inflation forecasting model with external regressors and seasonality. It came to my mind that a very useful information for prediction could be the consensus forecast of economists (obtained from Bloomberg or Refinitiv).

Is there a more sophisticated way to combine the information from consensus with my own prediction rather than (weighted) mean? I was thinking using Bayesian methods, but I couldn't find a package that allows to specify the prior distribution for forecasts. One of the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420186/incorporating-prior-information-into-time-series-prediction) refers to ba `bsts` package in `R`, which I am familiar with, but the approach in the answer uses the "prior" information as a regressor in model estimation. I do not have such an option, as I only have the consensus forecasts for the future.

Some simplification of my problem in code form:

```
set.seed(13)
require(bsts)

#Regressors
reg1 <- rnorm(100,0,0.1)
reg2<- rnorm(100,2,1)

#assume stationary mont-on-month inflation 
inflmm <- 0.05+1.2*reg1 +0.1*reg2 +rnorm(100,0,0.1)

#making train/test split
train <- data.frame(inflmm, reg1, reg2)[1:90,]
test <- data.frame(inflmm, reg1, reg2)[91:100,]

ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(),train$inflmm)
model4 <- bsts(inflmm ~ .,
               state.specification = ss,
               niter = 1000,
               data = train) 
plot(model4, "components")
plot(model4, "coef")

pred4 <- predict(model4, newdata = test, horizon = 10)
plot(test$inflmm, type = 'l', ylim = c(-0.3,0.8))
lines(pred4$median, col = 'red')

#assume that I have concesus forecasts that bear relevant information for prediction
consensus <- c(0,0,0,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2)
test$inflmm <- 0.5*test$inflmm+0.5*consensus

pred4 <- predict(model4, newdata = test, horizon = 10)
plot(test$inflmm, type = 'l', ylim = c(-0.3,0.8))
lines(pred4$median, col = 'red')
```